# Import statement doesn't work as expected with Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-import

I recently ported a django application from Python 2.7 to Python 3.3 with Django1.6b1.

My import statements wouldn't work anymore for custom module imports (User, views...) and I had to add a dot before these imports. Why ?

Example :

```
import EmailUser #worked with python 2.7 but doesn't work with 3.3    
import .EmailUser #works
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a bug; Python 3 forces explicit relative imports.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax):

> The only acceptable syntax for relative imports is `from .[module]
>   import name`. All import forms not starting with `.` are interpreted as
>   absolute imports. ([**PEP 0328**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328))

Also, `import .EmailUser` is invalid syntax in any Python version; it would have to be `from . import EmailUser`.

Comment: Thanks for the explication. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of "absolute imports", that is the imports that do not start with . are absolute and must be found in module path. In Python 2.6, 2.7 you can turn this on file-by-file basis by doing

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Comment: Thanks :D I didn't know.